# Determine the color of an image

Tags: python, image-processing, colors

I have a concern. I have to determine the dominant color of an image, **but the colors should be picked from a determined list of colors** (e.g red green blue red and white). I know that algorithms such as k-means determine the relevant colors in a more appropriate way, but i need that the colors comes from a list.
It should be simplier because it should be an algorithm with only one iteration (because assign directly the pixel to a cluster), but i do not know how to wirte the code in python (I am a beginner) and I not know if there is alòready a function that do this.
Thanks :)

Comment: "I don't know how to implement this" is not a question. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colors are points in a vector space.

You can define a metric between the dominant colors and the ones in your list. See e.g. the wikipedia page about [color difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference). The simplest but suboptimal one would be Euclidean distance in RGB space, which you could do with [**`np.linalg.norm`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html).

You could maybe find the dominant color first and then associate it to the one from your list which minimizes your chosen metric.

You could also do some kind of clustering (simple histogram binning, k-means, etc), associate each cluster to the color from your list which minimizes your  metric and then find the most represented one.